# Trimming a file with regular expressions / sed

Tags: regex, sed

I've got a file with several lines like this:

```
*wordX*-Sentence1.;Sentence2.;Sentence3.;Sentence4.
```

One of these Sentences may or may not contain wordX.
What I want is to trim the file to make it look like this:

```
*wordX*-Sentence1.;Sentence2.
```

Where Sentence3 was the first to contain wordX.

How can i do this with sed/awk?

Edit:

Here's a sample file:

```
*WordA*-This sentence does not contain what i want.%Neither does this one.;Not here either.;Not here.;Here is WordA.;But not here.
*WordB*-WordA here.;WordB here, time to delete everything.;Including this sentece.
*WordC*-WordA, WordB. %Sample sentence one.;Sample Sentence 2.;Sample sentence 3.;Sample sentence 4.;WordC.;Discard this.
```

And here is the desired output:

```
*WordA*-This sentence does not contain what i want.%Neither does this one.;Not here either.;Not here.
*WordB*-WordA here.
*WordC*-WordA, WordB. %Sample sentence one.;Sample Sentence 2.;Sample sentence 3.;Sample sentence 4.
```

Comment: If `Sentence[n].` contains `WordX`, delete to end of line?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This task is more suited to awk. Use following awk command:

```
awk -F ";" '/^ *\*.*?\*/ {printf("%s;%s\n", $1, $2)}' inFile
```

This assumes that the words your are trying to match are always wrapped in asterisks `*`.

Comment: How can i use that recursively for the whole file, without having to manually specify what is wordX (the word between *,s?

Comment: Is wordX always comes enclosed with 2 `*` ?

Comment: Yes, and the word differs from line to line.

Comment: `.*` will match as much as possible, so if any of the paragraphs contain a `*` you will end up matching too much. Does `.*?` work in awk? If not, maybe `[^*]*` would work better?

Comment: Doesn't work, for the sample file I provided, the output is:


    *WordA*-This sentence does not contain what i want.%Neither does this one.;Not here either.
    *WordB*-WordA here.;WordB here, time to delete everything.
    *WordC*-WordA, WordB. %Sample sentence one.;Sample Sentence 2.

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand your expected output. Can you explain clearly logic behind getting this output?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/-/;/;:a;s/^(\*([^*]+)\*.*);[^;]+\2.*/\1;/;ta;s/;/-/;s/;$//' file
```

Convert the `-` following the `wordX` to a `;`. Delete sentences containing `wordX` ( working from the back to the front of the line). Replace the original `-`.Delete the last `;`.

Comment: Did not work, here's the output:

    *WordA*-This sentence does not contain what i want.%Neither does this one.;Not here either.;Not here.
    *WordB*-WordA here.;WordB here, time to delete everything.;Including this sentece.
    *WordC*-WordA, WordB. %Sample sentence one.;Sample Sentence 2.;Sample sentence 3.;Sample sentence 4.;WordC.;Discard this.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r -e 's/\.;/\n/g' \
       -e 's/-/\n/' \
       -e 's/^(\*([^*]*).*\n)[^\n]*\2.*/\1/' \
       -e 's/\n/-/' \
       -e 's/\n/.;/g' \
       -e 's/;$//'
```

(edit: added the `-`:`\n` swaps to handle a match in the first sentence.)